# How does NextJS's <Image> component use the passed `quality` value?

Tags: next.js

NextJS's `<Image/>` component does a lot of amazing things. One optional prop is `quality` which is defined briefly in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#quality) as

> The quality of the optimized image, an integer between 1 and 100 where 100 is the best quality. Defaults to 75.

But what does this metric actually do? What is a 1 or 100 supposed to represent? Say two images of original size 10MB and 1MB are passed in how will the resultant images work at the different qualities? Is the image's rendered size factored in? Are there different compression algorithms used based on this number?

Answer (score 1):

I dug around in the NextJS source code and I think I have some more answers. Under the hood NextJS the sharp image library on the client side to optimize images (imported [line 41, used lines 510 & 757](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/server/image-optimizer.ts), also `@types/sharp` exist as a dependency in package.json).

The `quality` prop is passed directly to sharp (with one exception for AVIF images for which `max(0,quality-15)` is passed). [Sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) currently uses libvps under the hood.

I couldn't find exactly what algorithm libvps uses but `quality` seems to be a standard across other similar types of image compression tools (especially for jpeg).